# How do you recursively merge queues in C++? Assume they are already sorted

Tags: c++, recursion, merge, queue

I made a function that merges two sorted queues.

```
Queue<int> merge(Queue<int> a, Queue<int> b){
Queue<int> result;
while (!a.isEmpty() && !b.isEmpty()) {
    int a1 = a.peek();
    int b1 = b.peek();

    if (a1 < b1) {
        if (! result.isEmpty()) {
            if (result.back() > a1) {
                error("queue a is not sorted");
            }
        }
        result.add(a1); // add the element to the result and make sure to remove it from the
        a.dequeue(); // input queue so we don't get stuck in an infinite loop
    } else {
        if (! result.isEmpty()) {
            if (result.back() > b1) {
                error("queue b is not sorted");
            }
        }
        result.add(b1);
        b.dequeue();
    }
} while (!a.isEmpty()) {
    if (! result.isEmpty()) {
        if (result.back() > a.peek()) {
            error("queue a is not sorted");
        }
    }
    result.add(a.front());
    a.dequeue();
} while (!b.isEmpty()) {
    if (! result.isEmpty()) {
        if (result.back() > b.peek()) {
            error("queue b is not sorted");
        }
    }
    result.add(b.front());
    b.dequeue();
}
return result;}
```

Now, I am trying to merge *multiple* queues together, recursively. Here is my thought process so far:

1. Divide the input collection of k sequences into two halves, left and right.
2. Make a recursive call to recMultiMerge on the "left" half of the sequences to generate one combined, sorted sequence. Then, do the same for the "right" half of the sequences, generating a second combined, sorted sequence.
3. Using the binary merge function I made above, join the two combined sequences into the final result sequence, which is then returned.

I'm having trouble on the actual recursive call, because I can't figure out how to store the result and recurse again. Here is my attempt so far:

```
    Queue<int> recMultiMerge(Vector<Queue<int>>& all)
{
    Queue<int> result = {};

    Vector<Queue<int>> left = all.subList(0, all.size() / 2);
    Vector<Queue<int>> right = all.subList(all.size() / 2, all.size() / 2);

    if (all.isEmpty()) {
        return {};
    }
    else if (left.size() == 1) {
        return left[0];
    }
    else if (right.size() == 1) {
        return right[0];
    }
    else {
        Queue<int> leftCombined = recMultiMerge(left);
        Queue<int> rightCombined = recMultiMerge(right);
        result = merge(leftCombined, rightCombined);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem is, I can't get it to return more than just the first queue. Here is the problem illustrated in a test case:
on

```
Vector<Queue<int>> all = {{3, 6, 9, 9, 100}, {1, 5, 9, 9, 12}, {5}, {}, {-5, -5}, {3402}}
```

it yields

```
{3, 6, 9, 9, 100}
```

instead of

```
{-5, -5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 12, 100, 3402}
```

Any advice?

Comment: What is that formatting?  Typos, or is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explanation of why your code gives the results you see.

The first call to `recMultiMerge` has 6 queues.  `left` will be the first three (`{3, 6, 9, 9, 100}, {1, 5, 9, 9, 12}, {5}`), and `right` will be the last three (`{}, {-5, -5}, {3402}`).

Then you make a recursive call with `left`.  In that call, `all.size()` will be 3.  `left` will have one queue (`{3, 6, 9, 9, 100}`), and `right` will also only have one queue (`{1, 5, 9, 9, 12}`).  (I'm assuming the 2nd parameter to `Vector.subList` is a count.)  This will stop at the second if because `left.size() == 1`.  The result will be that first queue.

Now we're back at the first recursive call (having lost the 2nd and 3rd queues), and we again main a recursive call with `right` (which has 3 queues in it).  This will proceed like the last call did, returning the first queue (which in this case is empty) and losing the other two.

Then you merge those two queues (`{3, 6, 9, 9, 100}` and `{}`), resulting in your answer: `{3, 6, 9, 9, 100}`.

This reveals two problems:  Not properly dividing a Vector with an odd number of queues in it, and terminating the recursion too early (when the left half of the split only has one queue in it, even though the right half may not be empty).

Comment: cheers, this really helped. After some tinkering, I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a binary fold.

```
template<class X, class Op>
X binary_fold( span<X> elems, Op op );
```

or `std::vector<X>`, but I prefer `span` for this.

It splits `elems` into two pieces, then either recurses or calls `op` on it.

You can then test `binary_fold` with debugging code that simply prints the pieces on the left/right in some way, and you can see how the recursion plays out.

Once you have that, you plug back in your `merge` program and it should just work.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e51bff773d579f4).

Full code:

```
template<class X>
struct span {
    X* b = 0;
    X* e = 0;
    X* begin() const { return b; }
    X* end() const { return e; }

    std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
    X& front() const { return *begin(); }
    X& back() const { return *(end()-1); }
    X* data() const { return begin(); }
    bool empty() const { return size()==0; }


    span( X* s, X* f ):b(s),e(f) {}
    span() = default;
    span( X* s, std::size_t l ):span(s, s+l) {}

    span( std::vector<X>& v ):span( v.data(), v.size() ) {}

    template<std::size_t N>
    span( X(&arr)[N] ):span(arr, N) {}
    template<std::size_t N>
    span( std::array<X, N>& arr ):span(arr.data(), N) {}

    span except_front( std::size_t n = 1 ) const {
        n = (std::min)(n, size());
        return {begin()+n, end()};
    }
    span only_front( std::size_t n = 1 ) const {
        n = (std::min)(n, size());
        return {begin(), begin()+n};
    }
    span except_back( std::size_t n = 1 ) const {
        n = (std::min)(n, size());
        return {begin(), end()-n};
    }
    span only_back( std::size_t n = 1 ) const {
        n = (std::min)(n, size());
        return {end()-n, end()};
    }
};


template<class X, class Op>
X binary_fold( span<X> elems, Op op ) {
    if (elems.empty()) return {};
    if (elems.size() == 1) return elems.front();

    auto lhs = binary_fold( elems.only_front( elems.size()/2 ), op );
    auto rhs = binary_fold( elems.except_front( elems.size()/2 ), op );
    return op(std::move(lhs), std::move(rhs));
}
```